# Find the value of density of states at the Fermi energy using VASP

Tags: vasp, density-of-states, fermi-energy

`VASP` has a tag [NEDOS](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/NEDOS), which helps specify the # of points on which the DoS is evaluated. Other than that, we have [EMIN](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/EMIN) and [EMAX](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/EMAX), which help decide the range of energy in which DoS is evaluated at NEDOS evenly spaced grid-points. This procedure misses the exact fermi energy point, at least in all of my calculations. Is there a way to make the code explicitly calculate DoS at the Fermi energy? I wish to avoid interpolation due to certain concerns as relayed [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3567/validity-of-interpolation-for-density-of-states).

Comment: What concern do you have about interpolation?  What is being suggested is not interpolation as you say as well, it is peak broadening, which should be sufficient most of the time.

Comment: That was pointed out to me at https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3567/validity-of-interpolation-for-density-of-states.

Answer (score 8):

Let me suggest a simple answer, although I am not convinced you will get anything sufficently different for the fermi level than just using a converged grid.

- Consider a range of energies such as 10 eV.
- Set `EMIN=Fermi-5` and `EMAX=Fermi+5`
- Set `NEDOS=Anything Odd`

As a rule, you should always hit the middle point doing this and the middle point is the Fermi level since you defined it that way.  This should work in essentially any DFT calculator.

Comment: +1 for the quick answer, we haven't had a lot of hot network questions in a while! I've just edited the typesetting of DFT in case that's what you meant: You can revert the edit otherwise.

Comment: There are lots of more optimized grids you could use as well to hit the fermi level, but this was the quickest and easiest to remember solution I could think of.  Let me know if this makes any actual difference as I am curious.

Comment: @TristanMaxson, got the DoS at $E_F$. Other values match with the ones from the calculation without this workaround. The integrated DoS matches exactly. I was surprised because I expected to see the value of integrated DoS start from the DoS at EMIN, but it included all the DoS values.

Comment: Maybe at this point you can answer your own other question if you have an idea of how all of this makes a difference.